# Is it possible to visualise how graph of product of two functions look like?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

We can easily predict without calculating how a graph of sum of two functions will look like. And its helpful. 
Is it possible to do with product?

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced of the premise: just given the graphs of $\sin(10x)$ and $\sin(9x)$ would you easily be able to predict the shape of the graph of $\sin(10x) + \sin(9x)$?

Answer (score 0):

You know that it both functions are positive or both are negative at a point then their product will be positive. Otherwise the product will be negative. You also know that if either function is 0 at a point then the product will be (and that in fact these are the *only* places the product will be 0). Otherwise, if you haven't taken a calculus course there probably isn't a lot to easily find what the shape will look like except arguments like if the absolute value of one function is less than $1$ it will "shrink" the other function and otherwise it will "expand" it.

This is something I wondered often as a kid and didn't get a very good answer until I took a calculus course. After you've taken calculus, assuming the function behaves very nicely everywhere, the derivatives will tell you the type of information you're looking for.